# Static Initialization of openCV in android app

Tags: java, android, opencv, javacv

OK, I have no idea what is going on here, I have read many threads about this case and followed the reviews but unfortunately I have got no clue.

I have already read the openCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization) about static initialization. So I have copied openCV native libs to my `libs` folder.

Then I added this line to my code:

```
static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        // Handle initialization error
    }
}
```

and finally, I added this line:

```
 mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
```

inside `onCreate` method.

Now, When I run my app I have got these errors:

```
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548): Process: org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition, PID: 9548
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_calib3d
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:455)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.<clinit>(opencv_contrib.java:104)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.PersonRecognizer.<init>(PersonRecognizer.java:42)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.FdActivity$1.onManagerConnected(FdActivity.java:153)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.FdActivity.onCreate(FdActivity.java:232)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_calib3d
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     ... 18 more
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:455)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_calib3d.<clinit>(opencv_calib3d.java:94)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     ... 21 more
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     ... 22 more
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:455)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:85)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     ... 25 more
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     ... 26 more
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:455)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:97)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     ... 29 more
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     ... 30 more
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jniopencv_core from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition-32.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition-32]: findLibrary returned null
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:136)
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548):     ... 33 more
07-05 10:34:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(9548): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load tbb from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition-32.apk,library
```

I also have `javacpp.jar` and `javacv.jar` under my `libs` folder.

**EDIT[1](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization)-** After I have searched about this error, I figured out that I should have `openCV` library (not Android SDK, the openCV library for windows) on my system and I should also have its `bin` folder inside my environment variable `PATH`. It makes sense since `javacv` needs it to resolve objects.

Now I have not got any errors when I run my app in my device, but my application does not run. Every time I open it, the error message just popup and says `Unfortunately your app has stopped!!`. I think maybe its because of the incompatibility version issue between `openCV` and `JavaCV` libraries. Is it though?

Comment: it's complaining about com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_calib3d. that's a different package, not opencv's own android sdk. both bindings are unfortunately total uncompatible, reconsider , if you really need javacv.

Comment: @berak I didn't get your point. When I checked inside target folder libs (for example armeabi-v7a) which is under my libs folder, I can find 'libopencv_calib3d.a' for example. But why I have got this link errors, what should I do to make this work?

Comment: again, the opencv wrappers seem to find their libs (the 'static linking' part only caters for them), the javacv ones don't

Comment: @berak you mean I should install javacv on my OS? I thought if I add javacv jar files inside my project dependent libraries, there would be fine

Comment: no, i mean the opposite. try without javacv.

Comment: Why? what if I wanna use javacv? I don't wanna migrate to native style

Comment: what do you *need* javacv for, when you already got opencv's android javaapi working ?

Comment: @berak Ok, I am trying to use OpenCV Android library in my project. I imported it to my project and instead of **import static  com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;** I used: **import org.opencv.highgui.*;** for example. But now, I've got error in method 'cvLoadImage(String)'. So I think there are some methods which can be resolved by javacv and they're not implement in openCV library for Android. Is it though?

Comment: again, both apis are different and not compatible. also javacv mostly wraps opencv's deprecated c-api, that's why you should avoid it. you will have to use [highgui.imread()](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/highgui/Highgui.html#imread(java.lang.String)) instead.

Comment: So I think I should change my code almost entirely ;) Thank you for all your comments. Actually I tried to avoid changing my code, but it seems impossible.

Comment: at least, you will have to stick strictly to one or the other api. if you want static linking on android, you're bound to the opencv one, since it won't link for javacv(your original problem)